# How to disable derived class to be returned by GameObject.GetObjectsOfType?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a manager that saves data of every enemy. However, there will certainly be a situation when an enemy has custom values that have to be saved by other manager with its properties. I use `GameObject.GetObjectsOfType<EnemyController>()` to retrieve all objects with classes derived from `EnemyController`. The question is can I make a class derived from `EnemyController` which will not be returned by `GameObject.GetObjectsOfType<EnemyController>()`?

Comment: I guess this question should be moved to "Game Development" Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, since every `DerivedEnemyController : EnemyController` is an `EnemyController` per design (this is what you want using inheritance).

You'll have to split your inheritance logic:

```
public abstract class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour { /* contains all shared information */ }

public class RegularEnemyController : EnemyController { /* to be saved by manager */ }

public class SpecialEnemyController : EnemyController { /* to be saved by special manager */ }
```

Like that you can interpret all enemies as `EnemyController` and access shared information, but use `GameObject.GetObjectsOfType<RegularEnemyController>()` to only get the ones to be saved by your manager.

You might want to think about a different approach altogether since `GetObjectsOfType<T>` is A) not performant and B) seems not to be the functionality you are looking for.
For example you could have all enemies register at your manager, if they fulfill certain criteria (they can even deregister once they do not any more). In this scenario your base class could indeed register for saving, but a derived class could override this behaviour.

Example:

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {
    ...
    void Awake() => Init();
    protexted virtual void Init() => manager.Register(this);
}

public class NonRegEnemy : EnemyController {
    protected override void Init() { }
}
```